# Retaining inline code inside references in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

In Sphinx, if I have the following heading declaration:

```
.. _somestuff:

``this is code``, this is not!
==============================
```

It renders, like this:

### **`this is code`, this is not!**

Which is good, but, if I use the reference, e.g:

```
Have a look at :ref:`somestuff`
```

It loses the code formatting and renders like:

Have a look at [*this is code, this is not!*](http://s.tk)

instead of:

Have a look at [*`this is code`, this is not!*](http://s.tk)

---

Is it possible to retain the code formatting in the reference? And how would I go about it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now.  I'm pretty sure the `:ref:` role just pulls the link, and ignores any other rst formatting.  You might try reporting this to the Sphinx developers as a bug/feature request.

Comment: Here is a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666008/407651

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at `:ref:` documentation in its [official web site](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html) about inline markups:

> **:ref:**
>
> To support cross-referencing to arbitrary locations in any document,
>   the standard reST labels are used. For this to work label names must
>   be unique throughout the entire documentation ...

I think (as @Kevin Horn) it's no possible right now, because it's only used to create links (without rst formatting) with other sections in your project. Then if you write something like this:

```
.. _somestuff:

``this is code``, this is not!
==============================

.. _another_somestuff:

this is another code!
========================
```

If I link with these sections:

```
Have a look at :ref:`somestuff`
Have a look at :ref:`another_somestuff`
Have a look at :ref:`this link <somestuff>`
```

The result is:

---

Have a look at ***this is code, this is not!***

Have a look at ***this is another code!***

Have a look at ***this link***

---

The style is the same in all of them .

**Note**: the italic/bold words symbolize links