# In reStructuredText, how to put an inline literal inside of a hyperlink?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my reStructuredText document, I have a section defined like so:

```
Update the ``PATH`` Environment Variable
----------------------------------------
```

I would like to link to this section like so:

```
* `Update the ``PATH`` Environment Variable`_
```

But, when this code is rendered to HTML, it comes out looking like this:

- *Update the ``PATH`* Environment Variable`

I'd really like the environment variable `PATH` to appear in the literal style, but I am pretty new to this.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I can't think of a way to solve this. Nested inline markup is a problem. See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible.

Answer (score 8):

With a [workaround](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible), yes -- it is possible (hinted from @mzjn's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516306/#comment56777739_34516306)).

For example:

```
.. |dummy| replace:: Update the ``PATH`` Environment Variable
.. _dummy:

Update the ``PATH`` Environment Variable
----------------------------------------

* |dummy|_
```

This is achieved by taking advantage of the [replace directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replace).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations):

> If you place a label directly before a section title, you can reference to it with `` :ref:`label-name` ``.

Example:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```