# formatting a Sphinx reference

Tags: python-sphinx

If I use this RST source:

```
- :ref:`Naming Convention <naming>` --- we consistently 
  followed a certain naming convention
```

then I can get output that looks like this

- [Naming Convention](http://example.com/naming) — we consistently
  followed a certain naming convention

*but what can I do to make "Naming Convention" boldface*? RST doesn't seem to like the idea of nested formatting directives.

I've tried the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836544/44330 but it doesn't seem to work in this case (a `:ref:` rather than an HTML hyperlink)

I'm willing to write my own extension if necessary, as long as it's simple, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8091979/407651

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. That issue has formatting in the referenced section, not the section referencing it: in other words, if A references B, then question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091979 has the formatting in B and asks how to get that formatting to show up in A. My question is that if A references B, how can I add formatting in A.

Answer (score 3):

Does it help you to include a cssclass as the parent element of the reference? If the goal is to style link text selectively for specific links then you could do something like:

```
.. cssclass:: boldlink

:ref:`Naming Convention <naming>` --- we consistently followed a certain naming convention
```

Then define in custom.css:

```
.boldlink a { font-weight: bold; }
```

While you could override the CSS for all references, that would also restyle all the other links in the document:

```
span.std-ref { font-weight: bold; }
```